# Robocopy to copy files to a remote machine

Tags: deployment, service, continuous-integration, psexec, robocopy

I'm trying to write a robocopy command to copy files from my local computer to any one of my deployment servers

```
ROBOCOPY ../../MyService/bin/release/ \\remote-computer\\C:\services\myservice /MIR
```

and I get this error

```
The system detected a possible attempt to compromise security. 
Please ensure that you can contact the server that authenticated you.
```

This is expected as I haven't included any sort of security credentials in the command.

Is there a way to get this to work by including permissions?  I don't want to have to do this by sharing folders and stuff like that.  I've looked but I can't see anything in the documentation.

Should I do this with something like `psexec`?  Or perhaps I should be using something like powershell instead?

Comment: has anybody found a solution to this issue yet? I have same problem now .(

Answer (score 1):

Can you please take a look at this answer to see if this answers your question: [Robocopy commands to copy a file to over 50 remote machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805835/robocopy-commands-to-copy-a-file-to-over-50-remote-machines). Also, please take a look at this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938457.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing file paths on remote machines you need to reference the drive letter as a hidden share instead of just with a colon

I.e. C drive is on the remote machine becomes \remoteserver\C$\Filepath

Answer (score 0):

I got this for the first time after my VPN connection to a remote driver (H:) timed out.
I restored VPN connection, but still got this robocopy error.

I fixed this for me by just using Windows File Explorer and clicking my H: drive.  It refreshed, and I retried my robocopy batch file script and all went well.

(thumbs up)